# Jquery topic: editing text on a To-Do-List after adding text

Tags: jquery, html

It been a while since using Stack over flow and glad to get back in it, here my question. 
Im trying to make a simple to do list (link of what i done so far is here: http://lamp.cse.fau.edu/~mcuervo5/p4/ with the Jquery and html code when you "Inspect and look at sources"

I'm a simple "To-DOList" from scratch and 90% done (just need to do the Css part after). The Question I have is trying to make a "edit" button which the sole purpose of editing the text inside the textbox after adding it to the list. The Only problem i how do I write the function in order to let people edit the text. I have the edit button already but it inside the delete function and I dont know what I have to type to let it edit. thank you

PS: Ok, i haveing a hard time pasting the Jquery code so just click the link above the copy the soruce from the website
it should look like this for the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7JJx.jpg

also How do you paste Jquery code here next time, cause im reading the direction and it still not pasting correctly on stack over flow. thank you

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>The Reminder list</title>
```

```
<h1> The Reminder Friend </h1>

<form>

    <!-- textbox -->
    <input type="text" id="textbox" >

    <!--add button -->
    <input type="button" id= "Sumbit_Button" value="Add">

      <h3>Todo</h3>
    <div id = "Complete"> </div>

    <ul id="incomplete-tasks">

    </ul>

</form> 


 <footer>
    <h2> &copy  Copyright Mauricio Cuervo</h2>
</footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="p4.js"></script>   


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the approach that [Shtut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4613631/shtut) said.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
            //$('#incomplete-tasks').html("<P>I just replaced your stuff.</P>");
            $("#Sumbit_Button").click(function() {
                var textbox_Value = $("#textbox").val();
                $('#incomplete-tasks').append('<li><span contenteditable="false">' + textbox_Value + "</span>"
                                              + '<input/ style="display: none" class="new-value">'
                                              + "<button type='button' class='delete'>Delete</button>"
                                              + "<button type='button' class='edit'>Edit</button></li>");
            });
            $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.delete', function() {
                console.log('i am clicked');
               $(this).parent().remove();
            });

            $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.edit',  function () {
                $(this).siblings('input').show();
                $(this).siblings('.delete').hide();
                $(this).hide();
            });

            $('#incomplete-tasks').on('click', '.edit',  function () {
                $(this).siblings('input').show();
                $(this).siblings('span').hide();
                $(this).siblings('.delete').hide();
                $(this).hide();
            });

            $('#incomplete-tasks').on('keyup', '.new-value',  function (e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13){
                    $(this).siblings('span').text($(this).val()).show();
                    $(this).siblings('input').hide();
                    $(this).siblings('.delete').show();
                    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>The Reminder list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> The Reminder Friend </h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="textbox">
        <input type="button" id="Sumbit_Button" value="Add">
        <h3>Todo</h3>
        <div id="Complete"> </div>
        <ul id="incomplete-tasks">
        </ul>
    </form>
    <footer>
        <h2> &copy  Copyright Mauricio Cuervo</h2>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about having a hidden textbox per option- when clicking edit display the textbox and hide the option, when clicking enter take the value from the textbox and change the option innerHTML to the value.